# Using XMLDocument - How to change an attribute value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, xml-parsing

I am trying to replace a found attribute with a new value, but can not seem to get it....

XML Example

```
<department sysid="1" name="a" minAmt="0.00" maxAmt="0.00" isAllowFS="0" isNegative="0" isFuel="0" isAllowFQ="0" isAllowSD="0" isBL1="0" isBL2="0" isMoneyOrder="0">
  <category sysid="0" />
```

Code

```
            For Each node In xmldoc.SelectNodes("//department")
                'For Each node In nodeDepartment
                Dim a = node.getAttribute("isFuel").ToString
                If a = 0 Then
                    node.ChildNodes.Item(1).Attributes.getNamedItem("sysid").Value = "400"
                    Dim sName As String = node.getAttribute("name").ToString 'I get the value here
                    If Trim(sName) = "" Then
                        node.Attribute("name") = "A" 'I Error on this line 
                    End If
                End If
                lCount += 1
            Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [SetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) Method instead of GetAttribute.

```
If Trim(sName) = "" Then 

    node.SetAttribute("name", "A") 

End If
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but had the syntax wrong. Thank You!

Comment: You're welcome.  If this resolves your question, please do not forget to mark it as the accepted answer.